# Posição do aplicativo desktop

Tags: java, string, int

Pessoal boa tarde estou com um problema vou tentar explicar:

Criei um app desktop e preciso da sua posicao na tela para tirar uma foto...
1º passo
pegar `posY`,e `X` com `getX`,`GetY`, já fis.
coloquei esses valores em um arq propert;
quando inicio o app leio o arq e gravo em variável..ai que está o problema quando
converto a `string` em `int` volta 0 porque?

Answer (score 0):

Descobri o que estava errado. Eu digitei o código assim:

```
Integer.getInteger(prop.getProperty("getY"));
```

Mas o certo é:

```
Integer.parseInt(prop.getProperty("getY"));
```